# geometry nodes blender 3.0 proximity

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

How can I create a geo node like this (with vertex weight prixomity)in blender 3.0
[image]

I tried this and I was so close to get it but the "Geometry proximity" didn't work
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve? Just the text? An animation? Please show us what you want to have (can be a screenshot or e.g. a yt link)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxQhLDfQIi8&t=608s watch this

Comment: I want to fade my text with an object in the center of my text, then animate it..

Answer (score 3):

with this node tree:

[image]

you can get an animation like this:

[image]